# Sending Sockets with binary and ascii data

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to integrate with a company and they use sockets which i am not to familiar with

I can get connected no problem but i am having issues sending data based off what they want

they want what they call a header record which starts with the message length 
and 4 other fields that are integers and they want this in binary

then they want message data but want this in ascii encoding

I can not figure out how to do this im not sure if i should use a binary writer for the first part and try and add the ascii

since this is a byte[] i dont think it can be altered after the fact

can anyone give me suggestions or some samples that they would think that would work for me in this matter

Comment: Read four bytes from receive data into an array.  The use BitConvert to convert array to either int or uint.  BitConverter.ToUInt32(array,0);  You need to verify if length is going to be > 2^31 (unsigned int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to first create a `Message` class that will be *"convertible"* from and to the `byte[]` type. Then you can create a `NetStream` that derives from `Stream` and use this to send data through your specified `Socket`. It's an easy to maintain solution which does not require any additional knowledge about socket communication at all.
Code example :

```
// include these namespaces :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Message
{
    int m_MessageLength;
    // your other fields
    char m_OtherField1;
    char m_OtherField2;
    char m_OtherField3;
    char m_OtherField4;
    // message content as I assume is string
    string m_MessageContent;

    public Message(string message, int field1, int field2, int field3, int field4)
    {
        m_MessageConten = message;
        m_OtherField1 = field1;
        m_OtherField2 = field2;
        m_OtherField3 = field3;
        m_OtherField4 = field4;
    }

    public static explicit operator byte[](this Message message)
    {
        List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
        // 4 fields each 2bytes wide gives us 16 bytes
        // ASCII character is 7 bits wide but is packed into 8 bits which is 1byte
        // gives us the result of ( length_of_message * 1byte == length_of_message )
        buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(8 + m_MessageContent.Length));
        buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(m_OtherField1));
        buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(m_OtherField2));
        buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(m_OtherField3));
        buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(m_OtherField4));
        buffer.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(m_MessageContent));
        return buffer.ToArray();
    } 
}
```

Having this object you can just use `Socket.Send` method :

```
Message message = new Message("hello world", 1, 3, 3, 7);
meSocket.Send((byte[])message);
```

If that's not enough just let me know and I'll update this answer with more details.

Comment: There is no reason to do both a length prefix and a null terminator. The whole reason you use a null terminator is because you where not able to transmit the message length at the start.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Seams reasonable. I'll edit that, thank you :)

Comment: @m.rogalski quick question i see you say the ints are 4 bytes in this company pdf it looks like there are looking or 2bytes on the first 4 fields would that mean they are not intergers then?

Comment: @quatre432 It may mean that they use `char` or `short` both of which are 16bits wide in C#. I've edited my answer to use `char` but if you need then change it to `short` or whatever values you need

Comment: @m.rogalski i Upadeted the public to be char as well the bottom code it is not liking the this Message message for some werid reason type expected?

Comment: @quatre432 Can you describe in more details what _"not liking"_ mean?

Comment: @m.rogalski sorry, with this in there visual studio highlights red and says types required, also if i take this out it all fields below are red and says obkect ref required for not static field, i think this needs to be something else

Comment: @m.rogalski this helped a lot had to fiddle with it but in the end I can send what I need to the company, you think I can reverse to read what they send back?

Comment: @quatre432 Sorry for the late answer but I have been busy during weekend :) Of course you can reverse this and read it back. Best way would be to just read the documentation about protocol used and make class/structure that would act the oposite way to this one. Meaning it will convert from `byte[]` to you _( let's say )_ `IncommingMessage`